# decimal to binary converter

Tags: java

I would like to create a piece of code in java that will convert a decimal value to binary without using an in-built binary converter command.

But it doesn't work...

```
public class MainFrame {
public static void binary(int number) {

    String result = new String();

    int binaryValues[] = {1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};

    if (number == 0) {
        result = result + "0";
    } else if (number == 1) {
        result = result + "1";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            while(number >= binaryValues[i]) {
                if (number % binaryValues[i] >= 0) {
                    result = result + "1";
                    number -= binaryValues[i];
                } else {
                    result = result + "0";
    //              number -= binaryValues[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    binary(5);
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework and you have a code. Please explain what you have understood so far.

Comment: its not homework, i'm just interested in how to do it

Comment: Learning to program is both fun and frustrating. Writing everything from scratch is educating but sometimes it's better to know what is available from the api than writing it by yourself, like: 
Integer.toBinaryString(5)

Comment: I am aware of the toBinaryString command and if I needed to generate a binary value as a part of a larger program that is what I would use, but I was just interested in writing some code that would have the same result.

Comment: @Kennet - `Integer.toBinaryString(5)` has a different output. It does not print "leading zeros": the `Integer.toBinaryString(5)` result is `"101"` while this method returns (prints) `"00000000101"` (hope the number of zeros was a good guess, but you know what I mean ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from the else block:

```
number -= binaryValues[i];
```

Reason: if the number *is not* bigger than 2<sup>n</sup>, then you want to add `0` and do not want to substract 2<sup>n</sup>.

And remove the `while` statement, it's not necessary (unless all numbers are less then 2<sup>12</sup>). Just keep the for loop and the if/else.

And *finally*, the if condition doesn't take modulo but a minus. The following works for me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    if (number - binaryValues[i] >= 0) {
        result = result + "1";
        number -= binaryValues[i];
    } else {
        result = result + "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: that makes sense but its still not working

Comment: just the for-loop / if-else still dosn't do the trick :(

Comment: @Java - there were three logical errors in the algorithm - now it works as expected.

Comment: now I see, you don't even need to use % you just need to check that if the decimal value can have the binaryValue taken away from it then append a "1" else append a "0", basically

Answer (score 2):

For ints >= 0:

```
public class DecimalToBinary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dec = 127;
        StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            binary.insert(0, dec % 2);
            dec /= 2;
        } while (dec != 0);
        System.out.println(binary.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: well that works but i don't really underatand it

Comment: number % 2 is either 1 or 0, by applying '%' you are getting binary digits (from the right side) and by applying '/' you are moving to digit at higher position. 
It is like you you wanted to get decimal digits (try to apply dec%10 and dec/10). The only difference is that for binary you divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BinaryConversion {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
    int numerator = input.nextInt();
        int num = numerator;
        boolean runLoop = true;
    String digit = "";
    while(runLoop){
        int bin = numerator % 2;
    numerator = (numerator / 2);
    digit= bin+digit;
    if (numerator == 0) {
        break;
    }

    }
    input.close();
    System.out.println("The binary value of "+num+" is "+digit);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on how/why this works to resolve the question?